# не работает выдача роли за реакцию на disnake.py

Tags: python, discord, disnake

Ошибок не выдает, бот имеет права администратора, но роль не выдается.

Код:

```py
import disnake
from disnake import ChannelType
from disnake.ext import commands
from disnake.errors import NotFound


import json

from config import settings

intents = disnake.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.reactions = True
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=settings['prefix'], intents=intents)

role_reactions_dict = {}
json_file = "role_reactions.json"


def load_reactions():
    try:
        with open(json_file, "r") as file:
            return json.load(file)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return {}


def save_reactions(reactions):
    with open(json_file, "w") as file:
        json.dump(reactions, file)


role_reactions_dict = load_reactions()


@bot.command()
async def add_role_reaction(ctx, message_id: int, emoji: str, role: disnake.Role):
    message = None
    for channel in ctx.guild.channels:
        if channel.guild == ctx.guild and channel.type == ChannelType.text:
            try:
                message = await channel.fetch_message(message_id)
                break
            except NotFound:
                pass
    if not message:
        await ctx.send("Сообщение с указанным ID не найдено.")
        return
    await message.add_reaction(emoji)
    new_role = await ctx.guild.create_role(name=role.name, color=role.color)
    role_reaction = {"message_id": message_id, "emoji": emoji, "role_id": new_role.id}

    role_reaction["id"] = len(role_reactions_dict) + 1
    role_reactions_dict[role_reaction["id"]] = role_reaction
    save_reactions(role_reactions_dict)

    await ctx.send(f"Роль '{new_role.name}' успешно создана за реакцией на сообщение с ID {message_id} emoji {emoji}")


@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if not payload.guild_id:
        return

    for role_reaction in role_reactions_dict.values():
        if (payload.message_id == role_reaction["message_id"] and
                str(payload.emoji) == role_reaction["emoji"]):
            guild = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
            if guild is not None:
                role = guild.get_role(role_reaction["role_id"])
                if role is not None:
                    member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
                    if member is not None:
                        await member.add_roles(role, reason="Role added by reaction.")
                        try:
                            await member.add_roles(role, reason="Role added by reaction.")
                            print(f"Добавлена роль {role} пользователю {member}")
                        except Exception as e:
                            print(f"Ошибка при добавлении роли {role} пользователю {member}: {e}")
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Ошибки я не увидел и вот сугубо моё решение: Убедись, что у твоего бота есть необходимые права на управление ролями и сообщениями на сервере. Проверь, правильно ли указаны параметры при вызове команды add_role_reaction. Убедись, что message_id соответствует существующему сообщению, emoji имеет правильный формат, и role - существующая роль на сервере. Обрати внимание на логи бота при попытке добавления ролей. Если возникают какие-либо ошибки, они могут помочь тебе более точно идентифицировать проблему.

Comment: Ну вот, именно, ошибок никаких нет. У бота есть ещё команда !mute которая даёт роль мута на время и снимает, там все работает. При использование команды реакции бот отправляет сообщение, что все успешно и ставит свою реакцию на указанное сообщение, но когда человек ставит сам реакцию, то ничего не происходит

Comment: Хотя у меня сейчас появилась ещё 1 идея... Возможно я забыл зарегистрировать ивент в main.py